# Non-Borel subsets of [0,1] and a definition in an article

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem to answer: let $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a compact set, let $b\in B^{[0,1]}$ and let $\{\pi_{i};i\in [0,1]\}$ denote the canonical projections. Is the following a well-defined probability measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $B$:
$$ \beta(b)(E):=\int_{[0,1]}f_{E}(i) d\lambda(i) $$
where $f_{E}(i)=1$ if $\pi_{i}(b)\in E$ and $0$ otherwise? I have  attacked the problem as follows: all there is to show is that for each Borel-measurable set $E\subseteq B$ the function $f_{E}$ is measurable. Assume that $|B|\geq 2$ and $x\neq y$ elements of $B$, then $\{x\}$ is a Borel-measurable subset of $B$. Assume that there exists $Z\subseteq [0,1]$ not Borel measurable and define $b$ by:
$$\pi_{i}(b)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if }i\in Z\\ y & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
then $f_{\{x\}}^{-1}(\{1\})=Z$ and hence not Borel-measurable.

So the questions are the following:

1. Is there any non-Borel measurable subset $Z\subseteq [0,1]$? It seems that yes, as of the standard example (e.g. [here](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/NonMeasurableSet.pdf)).
2. Is there another way this could work out?
3. Am I doing something wrong?

The reason why I am reluctant to say **NO** is that this is a basic assumption in a published paper ([thou clicketh here, footnote 6](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.3982/ECTA7377/abstract)). This leads to another question; does my expression differ from the one used in the paper:
$$\beta(b)(E) = \int_{\{i\in[0,1]:b_{i} \in E\}} di$$

Thank you very much

Manuel

Answer (score 3):

The paper is not very explicit in how small players are modeled, but there are approaches that works at least for this issue.

Assume that actions by players are represented by measurable functions $b:[0,1]\to B$. Then the induced distribution on $B$ is simply given by $\beta(b)(E)=\nu\circ b^{-1}(E)$ with $\nu$ being the measure on the space of players. If $\nu$ is atomless, any measure on $B$ is induced by such a function. Since all players have the same preferences and information, they all have the same best responses so a distribution over players actions will simply a probability measure on $B$ supported on best responses.

Sannikov is of course not explicit in what he considers to be an action profile, but the natural assumption is that they are measurable functions and not anything in the product $B^{[0,1]}$. As a matter of fact, almost all functions in $B^{[0,1]}$ [are nonmeasurable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102386/is-a-random-subset-of-the-real-numbers-non-measurable-is-the-set-of-measurable) if $B$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you. I was playing around along the same lines. But in this case, what is a collection $(\pi_{i}(b_{t}))_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ that is progressively measurable? This would have to be reformulated as each projection is progressively measurable and for every $t\in [0,\infty)$ the map $i\mapsto \pi_{i}(b_{t})$ is measurable, amirite? However this might yield some trouble. They argue, not very exactly, that the small players optimize myopically by choosing $\pi_{i}(b_{t})$ in some $\arg\max$ over $B$. Wouldn't measurability possibly restrict the choice?

Comment: @M.Luethi What do you mean by "measurability restricting the choice"?

Comment: At each time $t$ the small players choose $\pi_{i}(b_{t})$ and it is later shown that $\pi_{i}(b_{t})$ satisfies a certain property. Then the simultaneous choice needs to be made under the restriction that the resulting $(\pi_{i}(b_{t}))_{i\in [0,1]}$ is a measurable function. That sounds messy. In our situation it is reasonable that $\pi_{i}(b_{t})$ is constant w.r.t. $i$ from symmetry of the payoff functions but I have no clue whether I can safely impose this restriction beforehand and then proceed as usual.

Comment: One more question just out of curiosity: do you think that -- being a mathematician -- Sannikov (I do not know much about Faingold) realized this as well as that the extension of $\sigma$ is not well-defined and decided to just ignore it for the sake of a Tier A publication or did he really not realize it (together with the fact that square roots of matrices are not well-defined)? I tend towards being a bit disillusioned at the moment.

Comment: I think joint measurability in time and players might be enough. I have heard varying assessments of Sannikov's work from people I respect.

Comment: Okay. I guess the value of the paper lies in the idea of how to model reputation in contuinuous time and not in the extension to continua of players then. That also sounds reasonable.

Comment: @M.Luethi I'm busy at the moment, but we could discuss thes issue some time in chat if you want. I'm working on games with "many" players.